# How did the Apollo-Soyuz test project affect the relationship between the USSR and USA during the cold war?

Tags: soviet-union, cold-war, spaceflight

Did the [Apollo-Soyuz test project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo%E2%80%93Soyuz_Test_Project) really impact the relationship of the the USA and USSR politically? And if so, in what way?

Comment: Hello Prosti, welcome to History:SE - what has your research revealed so far? Please take a few moments to take the [tour] and visit the [help], and review the topic on [ask]. Questions that show some initial research get better results here. I would be interested in following this question (and could probably provide some answers, but won't for now, hoping others will participate and learn along the way), I worked at NASA once upon a time. Good Luck!

Comment: I've added in a link to the subject of the question. For events that aren't completely common knowledge, its a good idea to either explain what they are in detail, or link to some external source that does that.

Answer (score 7):

The Apollo-Soyuz Test Project was the first spaceflight to include two participating nations working together with their own national spacecraft. The Americans sent up an Apollo command module, while the Russians launched a Soyuz spacecraft.

The Soyuz and Apollo spacecraft docked on July 17, 1975, in a demonstration of how well the rendezvous and docking systems of each spacecraft would work with each other. The combined crew of five people — three Americans, two Soviets — spent about two days in orbit working on experiments and conducting joint press conferences.

ASTP was a signal that the Space Race was over. The two nations, now fighting different foes other than themselves and facing budgetary restrictions for spaceflight, openly spoke of working together in future initiatives.

Comment: Expanding the final paragraph would help to answer the question of how this project affected the countries relationship.